# How to connect iBatis(myBatis) framework to IBM AS/400 (iSeries)

Tags: java, mybatis, ibm-midrange, ibatis

Is it possible to use myBatis for query on as/400 database? if so, can you give me a step by step procedure to achieve that.
Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Jdbc driver in jt400.jar. Then it works like (almost) like any other DB/2 database.